# How to achieve highest possible compression on an Excel file using Java

Tags: java, compression, zip, gzip

I have a system generated excel file (around 40-50 MB or more of size). I have to zip the file and send it over email. Currently I am using  Java 7 ZipOutputStream api to achieve the same (using Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION option). I also explored GZIPOutputStream api.
The results are OK, but I was wondering if there are any other APIs or third party libraries which can help achieve even better compression ratio and help reduce the compressed file size further. I am not bothered about how much time is taken to compress the file, or extract the file.

Comment: You could take a look at the Apache Compression Library, it offers a number of different algorithims

Comment: Currently exploring different methods provided by Apache Commons Compression

Answer (score 1):

Just to update other users on stackoverflow, I tried testing various options (ZIP, GZ, XZ, 7z) compressing my 30 MB excel file. And I could achieve best compression results with XZ format.

Comment: Hi Anil, same requirement with you that i need generate excel and compress it, could you share you code, it will save my time if it's ok, thanks!

Comment: Sure KD, I'll share by weekend